# Add breadcrumbs to business manager

Tags: commerce-cloud

In my template I have this

```
<isbreadcrumb name1="${pdict.MainmenuName}" url1="${TOP_URL}" name2="Foo" />
```

My breadcrumb should be `Merchant Tools / Site Preferences / Foo`. However I am only getting this `Foo` as a breadcrumb in business manager.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What are you using, is it pipelines, SGJC or SFRA?

Comment: I am using SFRA

Comment: then you can add the breadcrumbs to the array provided by the controller and then just use `<isloop>` to iterate through them. Its pretty simple. Its a function in the file `cartridge/scripts/helpers/productHelpers` called `getAllBreadcrumbs` and is also used in `app_storefront_base` cartridge `Search` controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu Items are added in the manner

```
<isbreadcrumb
    name1="Merchant Tools" url1="${URLUtils.url('SiteNavigationBar-ShowSiteOverview')}"
    name2="Site Preferences" url2="${URLUtils.url('SiteNavigationBar-ShowMenuitemOverview', 'CurrentMenuItemId', 'site-prefs')}"
    name3="Your menu item" url3=""
 />
```

Comment: This isnt dynamic, you you have to write this in every template that you use manually. Using a dynamic approach is better.